# Rust ndarray: how to pass a slice as pointer array (&[T]) to function and mutable pointer array (&mut [T])?

Tags: rust, arguments, rust-ndarray

I have a 3-dimensional array `Array3` of the ndarray crate, and I would like to pass a slice of it as an array (`&[T]`) to a function, but can't figure out how. I found `slice()` and `as_slice()` methods, among similar others, but they require the data to be contiguous, or they return `None` instead.
For instance, something like this:

```
fn foo<T>(a: &[T], b: &mut [T]) {
    // do stuff
}

fn main() {

    let a = array![
        [
            [1.55, 0.0, 0.45, 0.0, 0.25], 
            [1.0, 0.55, 0.45, 0.0, 0.25], 
            [1.0, 0.55, 0.0, 0.0, 0.25],
        ],
        [
            [1.0, 0.0, 0.45, 0.65, 0.25], 
            [1.0, 0.55, 0.45, 0.65, 0.25], 
            [1.0, 0.55, 0.0, 0.65, 0.25],
        ],
        [
            [1.0, 0.0, 0.45, 0.65, 0.0], 
            [1.0, 0.55, 0.45, 0.65, 0.0], 
            [1.45, 0.55, 0.0, 0.65, 0.0],
        ],
    ];

    let mut b = array![
        [1.0, 0.0, 0.0],
        [1.0, 0.0, 0.0],
        [1.0, 0.0, 0.0],
    ];

    foo(
        a.slice(s![.., 0, 0]).as_slice().unwrap(), 
        b.slice_mut(s![.., 0]).as_slice_mut().unwrap(),
    );
}
```

How can I pass these slices in order to treat them as an array and mutable array?
From the documentation, I am having difficulty finding out.

Comment: To be clear here, is your issue that you can't take a mutable and immutable reference to the same thing simultaneously, or that you the slice methods don't allow capturing the data you like in the order you like? More succinctly, what precisely is the error you're facing here?

Comment: @naiveai, the error I get is "panicked at 'called `Option::unwrap()` on a `None` value'". I guess that when I do slice I am getting None since data is not contiguous as described in the documentation (it says: "Return the array’s data as a slice, if it is contiguous and in standard order. Return None otherwise.").

Comment: A slice *has* to be contiguous in memory. It's impossible to construct a slice of non-contiguous elements without copying the data to a new location, which is expensive and requires allocation. `as_slice` won't do it automatically since `as_` methods are supposed to be low- or zero-cost conversions.

Comment: You might want to pass a slice of references instead.

Comment: *but they require the data to be contiguous* - just to clarify, that's not a whim of those functions. Slices are contiguous **by definition**.

Comment: @user4815162342, Isn't the data of the array that must be contiguous so it can return the slice? If the slice is contiguous, why is this returning None? I'm confused!

Comment: @cafce25, I don't understand what you mean. Are you saying to pass `&a.slice...`?

Comment: I mean you want `&[&T]` or `&mut [&mut T]` if your type is not copy or you need to mutate inplace.